# AbstractBootstrap#handler vs. ServerBootstrap#childHandler for ServerBootstrap?

Tags: netty

I'd like to revivify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446922/what-is-the-difference-between-handler-channelhandler-c-and-childhandler-chan) one and [Manish Maheshwari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124076/manish-maheshwari)'s answer, in particular. Where is documented that

> The `handler`, which is defined in the `AbstractBootstrap` is used when writing Netty based **clients**.

and

> When writing Netty based **servers** [use] `childHandler` as defined in the `ServerBootstrap`.

In other words, where is the difference in

```scala
val b = new ServerBootstrap()
b.group(boss, wrkr)
 .channel(classOf[NioServerSocketChannel])
 .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer[SocketChannel]() {
   override def initChannel(ch: SocketChannel): Unit =
     ch.pipeline()
       .addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
       .addLast(new StringDecoder())
       .addLast(new StringEncoder())
 })
```

and

```scala
val b = new ServerBootstrap()
b.group(boss, wrkr)
 .channel(classOf[NioServerSocketChannel])
 .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer[SocketChannel]() {
   override def initChannel(ch: SocketChannel): Unit =
     ch.pipeline()
       .addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       .addLast(new StringDecoder())
       .addLast(new StringEncoder())
 })
```

Answer (score 9):

`handler` registers a channel handler for the **parent** channel
`childHandler` registers a channel handler for **child** channels
The seemingly same handlers listen to events on different channels and have different behaviors.

In the case of `LoggingHandler`, the first one logs events happened in the parent channel, which includes port binding and accepting new connections. So it produces logs (simplified and commented) like below:

> // parent channel registered
>   `INFO - [id: 0xb94a8e7c] REGISTERED`
>   // parent channel binds to localhost:8009
>   `INFO - [id: 0xb94a8e7c] BIND: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8009`
>   // parent channel active
>   `INFO - [id: 0xb94a8e7c, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8009] ACTIVE`
>    // parent channel accepts new connection, child channel with id 0xe507ce8f created
>   `INFO - [id: 0xb94a8e7c, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8009] RECEIVED: [id: 0xe507ce8f, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8009 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:54398]`

Suppose the child channel reads the data in the request, the logger in your second will produce something like:

> // child channel registered
>   `INFO - [id: 0x15fee362, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8009 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55459] REGISTERED`
>   // child channel active
>   `INFO - [id: 0x15fee362, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8009 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55459] ACTIVE`
>   // child channel received 7 bytes of data, "hello\r\n"
>   `INFO - [id: 0x15fee362, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8009 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55459] RECEIVED: 7B`
>   // logs the hex dump of the received data
>   
>            `+-------------------------------------------------+
>            |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
>   +--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
>   |00000000| 68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a                            |hello..         |
>   +--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+`

Comment: This kind of information should be easy to find in the docs, it's a shame that we need to come to SO to get such basic info.

Comment: Remember '**Channels are hierarchical**': A Channel can have a parent depending on how it was created. For instance, a `SocketChannel`, that was accepted by `ServerSocketChannel`, will return the `ServerSocketChannel` as its parent on `parent()` *(from https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html)*